# Cannot intercept values from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

I'm trying to simply move some values into textboxes when a listbox has selected the text.

Then, I'm trying to build all the text into one link.

However, when debugging using Chrome or Firefox, my jquery events **when the listboxes are being selected are not even being hit.**

Can someone please inform me what I'm doing wrong? I don't think I've had this issue before....

Here is my html: Note that the _guid variable is in a value called "PartnerGuid" above the written html....

Note that the listbox values are populated correctly.

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Link Builder</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.url, Model.urlOptions, "Select a url...", new { style = "width:180px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3 offset1">
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.pbid, Model.pbidOptions, "Select a pbid...", new { style = "width:180px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3 offset1">
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ldid, Model.ldidOptions, "Select a ldid...", new { style = "width:180px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="controls">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txturl" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtpbid" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtldid" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="control-group span9">
                <div class="controls">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtlink" maxlength="250" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="control-group span5 offset1">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="button" name="build" value="build" id="build" class="btn btn-success">Build Link</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

### Here is my JS

```
var txturl = $('#url').val($("#url option:selected").text());
        var txtpbid = $("#txtpbid").val($("#pbid option:selected").text());
        var txtldid = $("#txtldid").val($("#ldid option:selected").text());
        var _guid = $("#PartnerGuid").val();

        $('#build').click(function (e) {
            $("#txtlink").val("");
            $("#txtlink").val(txturl + "Routes/?ptid=" + _guid + "&pbid=" + txtpbid + "&ldid=" + txtldid);
            return false;
        });
```

### JS CHANGE:

I changed my JS to the following, but still doesn't work. The reason it still doesn't work is because there are no variables on the page (if you check my DropDownListFor model names (url, pbid, ldid) do not appear in the page.

I don't know why.

I'm using MVC with a parent page. The html & js are in the Partial (child) page.

However, I know that when during debugging, you have to look at the parent page as none of it (html or JS) will be in the child page.

What can I do next????

### Here is the pertinent updated JS:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="control-group span3">
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.url, Model.urlOptions, "Select a url...", new { style = "width:180px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3 offset1">
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.pbid, Model.pbidOptions, "Select a pbid...", new { style = "width:180px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group span3 offset1">
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ldid, Model.ldidOptions, "Select a ldid...", new { style = "width:180px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You don't have any listeners for your select boxes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You don't have any code for listening to when a select changes.

Comment: Add a jquery .change() event for your listboxes then get your values https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery .change() function to achieve your desired result.  Take the following example:

```
<!-- html -->
<select id="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<script>
   // Javascript
   $(document).on('change','#car',function(){
       selectedCar = $(this).val();
       alert(selectedCar);
   });
</script>
```

Here's a link to a jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/94Lx50at/

Comment: Josh, check out my edit... That's what I did, but I don't see any values in my page source with those ID values I have in my HTML.

Comment: What is the id of your listbox or select?